# Google maps marker clustering not working with infoWindow and fitBounds

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to create a Google map that has 
a) infoWindows on click, 
b) fitBounds on load and 
c) clustering of markers.

I've been  able to get the first two working but can't figure out why the clustering is not working. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
  <script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: {
        lat: -31.730513,
        lng: 132.008632
      }
    });
    setMarkers(map);
  }

  // markers variable
  var locations = [
    ['Cairns', -16.978165, 145.712778, 6],
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 5],
    ['Wollangong', -34.439390, 150.796039, 4],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Mandurah', -32.557420, 115.783668, 2],
    ['Perth', -32.080768, 115.778525, 1]

  ];

  // info window variable
  var locInfo = [
    ['<div class="map-text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p></div>'],
  ];

  // Adds markers to the map.
  function setMarkers(map) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var marks = locations[i];
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(marks[1], marks[2]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
      });
      bounds.extend(myLatLng);
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        marker, i;
      // Add info window to marker    
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infoWindow.setContent(locInfo[i][0]);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);
  }

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/benct/vpc613pe/

Comment: You are creating a `MarkerClusterer`, but you aren't adding your markers to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps MarkerClusterer either doesn't work or hides all markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945314/google-maps-markerclusterer-either-doesnt-work-or-hides-all-markers)

Comment: Thank @geocodezip - however when I add the markers to the cluster, the infoWindows stop working once the cluster has been selected e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/benct/7oeapd9h/

Comment: You have a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` on this line `infoWindow.setContent(locInfo[i][0]);` (the `locInfo` array only has one entry)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want. But markerClustering code is below.

```
//original code
//var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);

var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(marks[1], marks[2])
  });
});
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

Comment: Thanks @Otsuki Takaya -  Unfortunately the markerClustering code in the format you recommend doesn't appear to fix my problem. I am looking to have multiple markers on a google map with 3 part functionality -  a) infoWindows on click, b) fitBounds on load and c) clustering of markers. Thanks