# I am trying to add marker clusters to my google maps script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am trying to add var markerCluster to my google maps script but after creating a new layout for my markers I cannot find a suitable place for var markerCluster to fit without causing my maps or markers not to display.

I have tried to add var  markerCluster to most areas of my script. I am now starting to wonder if I have to change the layout completely.

```
var map;
var InforObj = [];
// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });


var centerCords = {
    lat: 16.058324,
    lng: 108.277000
};

var markersOnMap = [{
        placeName: ' <b>Ho-Chi-Minh City</b>  <br>' +
            'Ho Chi Minh City (commonly known as Saigon) is a city in southern Vietnam. <br>' +
            'Famous for the pivotal role it played in' +
            'the Vietnam War. Its also known for its French colonial landmarks,' +
            'including Notre-Dame Cathedral, made entirely of materials imported from France,' +
            'and the 19th-century Central Post Office. Food stalls line the city’s streets,' +
            'especially around bustling Bến Thành Market.',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 10.775844,
            lng: 106.701756
        }]
    },
     {
        placeName: "<b>Grand Mercure Danang (Da Nang City)</b> <br>" +
            '<b>Address:</b> Zone of the Villas of Green Island, Lot A1, Đà Nẵng 084511, Vietnam. <br>'+  
            '<b>Five Star Hotel</b> - ☆☆☆☆☆   '   ,
        icon: 'pin.png',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 16.048297,
            lng: 108.226951
        }]
    },
    {
        placeName: '<b>Da Nang City</b> <br>' +
            'Da Nang is a coastal city in central Vietnam known for its sandy beaches and history' +
            'as a French colonial port. Its a popular base for visiting the inland <b>Bà Nà</b> hills' +
            'to the west of the city. Here the hillside <b>Hải Vân</b> Pass has views of Da Nang Bay' +
            'and the Marble Mountains. These 5 limestone outcrops are topped with pagodas and hide' +
            'caves containing Buddhist shrines.',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 16.068000,
            lng: 108.212000
        }]
    },
    {
        placeName: "<b>Dalat Hôtel du Parc (Dalat City)</b> <br>" +
            '<b>Address:</b> 15 Đường Trần Phú, Phường 3, Thành phố Đà Lạt, Lâm Đồng, Vietnam',
        icon: 'pin.png',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 11.9367,
            lng: 108.4390
        }]
    },
    {
        placeName: "<b>Nhà gỗ - The Wooden House Restaurant (Dalat City)</b> <br>" +
            '<b>Address:</b> 26 Đường Nguyễn Đình Chiểu, Phường 9, Thành phố Đà Lạt, Lâm Đồng, Vietnam',
        icon: 'pin.png',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 11.9505,
            lng: 108.4582
        }]
    },
    {
        placeName: '<b>Dalat City</b> <br>' +
            '<b>Đà Lạt</b>, the capital of <b>Lâm Đồng</b> Province in southern Vietnam’s Central Highlands,' +
            'is centered around a lake and golf course, and surrounded by hills, pine forests,' +
            'lakes and waterfalls. Known as the “City of Eternal Spring” for its distinctive temperate' +
            'climate, Đà Lạt was developed as a resort by the French in the early 1900s,' +
            'and many reminders of its colonial heritage remain.',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 11.936230,
            lng: 108.445259
        }]
    },
    {
        placeName: "<b>Beaulieu Boutique Hotel (Hue City)</b> <br>" +
            '<b>Address:</b> 15 Pham Ngu Lao, Hue, Vietnam',
        icon: 'pin.png',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 16.4691,
            lng: 107.5947
        }]
    },
    {
        placeName: "<b>Hanh Restaurant (Hue City)</b> <br>" +
            '<b>Address:</b> 11 Đường Phó Đức Chính, Phú Hội, Tp. Huế, Phú Hội, Vietnam',
        icon: 'pin.png',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 16.4663,
            lng: 107.5950
        }]
    },
    {
        placeName: '<b>Hue City</b> <br>' +
            'Huế is a city in central Vietnam that was the seat of Nguyen Dynasty emperors and the' +
            'national capital from 1802 to 1945. A major attraction is its vast,' +
            '19th-century <b>Đại Nội Citadel</b>, surrounded by a moat and thick stone walls.' +
            'It encompasses the Imperial City, with palaces and shrines;' +
            'the Forbidden Purple City (<b>Tử cấm thành</b>), once the emperor’s home;' +
            'and a replica of the Royal Theater.',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 16.463713,
            lng: 107.590866
        }]
    },
    {
        placeName: "Vietnam (Hanoi Cooking Centre)",
        icon: 'pin.png',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 21.054374,
            lng: 105.837032
        }]

    },
    {
        placeName: "Vietnam (Fortuna Hotel, Hanoi)",
        icon: 'pin.png',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 21.0215,
            lng: 105.8178
        }]

    },
    {
        placeName: '<b>Hanoi</b> (<b>Capital City</b>) <br>' +
            'is known for its centuries-old architecture and a rich culture with Southeast Asian,' +
            'Chinese and French influences. At its heart is the chaotic Old Quarter, where the narrow' +
            'streets are roughly arranged by trade. There are many little temples,' +
            'including Bach Ma, honoring a legendary horse,' +
            'plus Đồng Xuân Market, selling household goods and street food.',
        LatLng: [{
            lat: 21.027763,
            lng: 105.834160
        }]
    }
];



window.onload = function() {
    initMap();
};


function addMarker() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
        var contentString = '<div id="content"><p>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName +
            '</p></div>';

        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
            map: map
        });

        const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            maxWidth: 200
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            closeOtherInfo();
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
            InforObj[0] = infowindow;
        });
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
            closeOtherInfo();
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
            InforObj[0] = infowindow;
        });
    }
}

function closeOtherInfo() {
    if (InforObj.length > 0) {
        /* detach the info-window from the marker ... undocumented in the API docs */
        InforObj[0].set("marker", null);
        /* and close it */
        InforObj[0].close();
        /* blank the array */
        InforObj.length = 0;
    }
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: centerCords
    });

    addMarker();
}
```

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps MarkerClusterer either doesn't work or hides all markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945314/google-maps-markerclusterer-either-doesnt-work-or-hides-all-markers)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. create the MarkerClusterer in the `addMarker` function (create the required `markers` array when you create the markers).
2. create the MarkerClusterer in the `initMap` function, add each marker to it as you create it.

The [example in the documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) does it the first way.

```
function addMarker() {
  var markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
    var contentString = '<div id="content"><p>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName +
      '</p></div>';

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
      map: map
    });

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 200
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      closeOtherInfo();
      infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
      InforObj[0] = infowindow;
    });
    marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
      closeOtherInfo();
      infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
      InforObj[0] = infowindow;
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qmbthn05/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var InforObj = [];
// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.

var centerCords = {
  lat: 16.058324,
  lng: 108.277000
};

var markersOnMap = [{
    placeName: ' <b>Ho-Chi-Minh City</b>  <br>' +
      'Ho Chi Minh City (commonly known as Saigon) is a city in southern Vietnam. <br>' +
      'Famous for the pivotal role it played in' +
      'the Vietnam War. Its also known for its French colonial landmarks,' +
      'including Notre-Dame Cathedral, made entirely of materials imported from France,' +
      'and the 19th-century Central Post Office. Food stalls line the city’s streets,' +
      'especially around bustling Bến Thành Market.',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 10.775844,
      lng: 106.701756
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: "<b>Grand Mercure Danang (Da Nang City)</b> <br>" +
      '<b>Address:</b> Zone of the Villas of Green Island, Lot A1, Đà Nẵng 084511, Vietnam. <br>' +
      '<b>Five Star Hotel</b> - ☆☆☆☆☆   ',
    icon: 'pin.png',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 16.048297,
      lng: 108.226951
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: '<b>Da Nang City</b> <br>' +
      'Da Nang is a coastal city in central Vietnam known for its sandy beaches and history' +
      'as a French colonial port. Its a popular base for visiting the inland <b>Bà Nà</b> hills' +
      'to the west of the city. Here the hillside <b>Hải Vân</b> Pass has views of Da Nang Bay' +
      'and the Marble Mountains. These 5 limestone outcrops are topped with pagodas and hide' +
      'caves containing Buddhist shrines.',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 16.068000,
      lng: 108.212000
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: "<b>Dalat Hôtel du Parc (Dalat City)</b> <br>" +
      '<b>Address:</b> 15 Đường Trần Phú, Phường 3, Thành phố Đà Lạt, Lâm Đồng, Vietnam',
    icon: 'pin.png',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 11.9367,
      lng: 108.4390
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: "<b>Nhà gỗ - The Wooden House Restaurant (Dalat City)</b> <br>" +
      '<b>Address:</b> 26 Đường Nguyễn Đình Chiểu, Phường 9, Thành phố Đà Lạt, Lâm Đồng, Vietnam',
    icon: 'pin.png',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 11.9505,
      lng: 108.4582
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: '<b>Dalat City</b> <br>' +
      '<b>Đà Lạt</b>, the capital of <b>Lâm Đồng</b> Province in southern Vietnam’s Central Highlands,' +
      'is centered around a lake and golf course, and surrounded by hills, pine forests,' +
      'lakes and waterfalls. Known as the “City of Eternal Spring” for its distinctive temperate' +
      'climate, Đà Lạt was developed as a resort by the French in the early 1900s,' +
      'and many reminders of its colonial heritage remain.',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 11.936230,
      lng: 108.445259
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: "<b>Beaulieu Boutique Hotel (Hue City)</b> <br>" +
      '<b>Address:</b> 15 Pham Ngu Lao, Hue, Vietnam',
    icon: 'pin.png',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 16.4691,
      lng: 107.5947
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: "<b>Hanh Restaurant (Hue City)</b> <br>" +
      '<b>Address:</b> 11 Đường Phó Đức Chính, Phú Hội, Tp. Huế, Phú Hội, Vietnam',
    icon: 'pin.png',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 16.4663,
      lng: 107.5950
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: '<b>Hue City</b> <br>' +
      'Huế is a city in central Vietnam that was the seat of Nguyen Dynasty emperors and the' +
      'national capital from 1802 to 1945. A major attraction is its vast,' +
      '19th-century <b>Đại Nội Citadel</b>, surrounded by a moat and thick stone walls.' +
      'It encompasses the Imperial City, with palaces and shrines;' +
      'the Forbidden Purple City (<b>Tử cấm thành</b>), once the emperor’s home;' +
      'and a replica of the Royal Theater.',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 16.463713,
      lng: 107.590866
    }]
  },
  {
    placeName: "Vietnam (Hanoi Cooking Centre)",
    icon: 'pin.png',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 21.054374,
      lng: 105.837032
    }]

  },
  {
    placeName: "Vietnam (Fortuna Hotel, Hanoi)",
    icon: 'pin.png',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 21.0215,
      lng: 105.8178
    }]

  },
  {
    placeName: '<b>Hanoi</b> (<b>Capital City</b>) <br>' +
      'is known for its centuries-old architecture and a rich culture with Southeast Asian,' +
      'Chinese and French influences. At its heart is the chaotic Old Quarter, where the narrow' +
      'streets are roughly arranged by trade. There are many little temples,' +
      'including Bach Ma, honoring a legendary horse,' +
      'plus Đồng Xuân Market, selling household goods and street food.',
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 21.027763,
      lng: 105.834160
    }]
  }
];

window.onload = function() {
  initMap();
};

function addMarker() {
  var markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
    var contentString = '<div id="content"><p>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName +
      '</p></div>';

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
      map: map
    });

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 200
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      closeOtherInfo();
      infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
      InforObj[0] = infowindow;
    });
    marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
      closeOtherInfo();
      infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
      InforObj[0] = infowindow;
    });
    // marker.addListener('mouseout', function () {
    //     closeOtherInfo();
    //     infowindow.close();
    //     InforObj[0] = infowindow;
    // });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });
}

function closeOtherInfo() {
  if (InforObj.length > 0) {
    /* detach the info-window from the marker ... undocumented in the API docs */
    InforObj[0].set("marker", null);
    /* and close it */
    InforObj[0].close();
    /* blank the array */
    InforObj.length = 0;
  }
}

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: centerCords
  });

  addMarker();
}
```

```css
html,
body, #map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and help, it has furthered my knowledge plus means I can continue with my project!

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).